# Convert json array to list of json(raw) strings

Tags: java, json, jackson

I've some json data like this:

```
[{"id":"someid","name":"some name"}, {"id":"some other id", "name":"a name"}]
```

I want to get the json objects in the above array aslist of strings like

(each string is json object in string form, `(List<String>)`)

(For simplicity

```
 [ {"id":"someid","name":"some name"},{"id":"some other id", "name":"a name"}
```

I tried using jackson's TypeReference> but it is causing consituents parts like id, someid into the list elements instead of making each json object a string element.

I also tried using jackson TypeReference>, this time I'm getting the number of objects correctly, but all the double quotes are gone and ':' are converted to '=', so it converted to java object not a json raw string.

I'm getting like [{id=someid,name=somename},{id=some other id, name=a name}]

I'm interested to know how to do this using Jackson library.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: please post the code you have tried, we will make an effort to fix it but no one will do the work for you

Comment: I do not understand what is the desired output. a json object is not a list, it is a map of keys and values. please give an example of the desired list contents

Comment: @sharonbn I want to convert a json array to list of string such that each is string is a raw json object of the original json array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to achieve the desired to result using JSONArray from json library. For any one comes across this question I'm posting this.

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(jsonString);
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String());
for(int i = 0 ; i < jsonArray.length();i++){
    list.add(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i));
}
```

However I'm still interested to know how to do this using Jackson library alone.

Comment: Did you ever find out how to do this with Jackson?

Comment: @ArtemioRamirez I moved on ;)

Comment: I was hoping you could help me out, but I managed to do it. If you ever care to know: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36846055/json-string-array-into-java-string-list

Comment: @ArtemioRamirez thanks, but the double quotes are unescaped in my question and each string is a json object.

Comment: Oh, it seems I looked at so many questions I got confused and thought you were also trying to do the same as I was. My bad

Answer (score 1):

Use org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser to parse JsonArray String to JsonArray Object.

```
    JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
    JSONArray arr = (JSONArray) parser.parse(jsonArray);
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (Object jsonObject : arr) {
        System.out.println("jsonObject>>"+jsonObject);
        list.add(jsonObject.toString());
    }
```

Here the prepared list contains json(raw) strings as you desire. Hope it will help you

Comment: Thanks for the answer.. equivalently I could achieve it using JSONArray. But I'm interested to know if there is a way to do it using Jackson library

Answer (score 0):

jsonArray.getJSONObject() method returns an instance of JSONObject. So, you either need to change the return value to `List<JSONObject>` or within your for loop, call jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).toString() to return a `List<String>`