# Json String array into Java String list

Tags: java, json, jackson, java-8

I have a webservice that returns a list of strings, only a list of strings:

```
["string1","string2","string3"]
```

How can I convert this into an `ArrayList<String>` in java? I'm trying to use jackson as I know you can convert Json to objects with it, but I can't find an example of a case like this.

Comment: You do not need a jackson for this

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ So, how would I do it natively then?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For anyone else who might need this:

```
String jsonString = "[\"string1\",\"string2\",\"string3\"]";
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
List<String> strings = mapper.readValue(jsonString, List.class);
```

Comment: This throws an unchecked exception warning FYI.

Answer (score 2):

As ryzhman said, you are able to cast it to a List, but only of the object (JSONArray in ryzhman's case) extends the ArrayList class.
You don't need an entire method for this. You can simply:

```
List<String> listOfStrings = new JSONArray(data);
```

Or if you are using IBM's JSONArray (com.ibm.json.java.JSONArray):

```
List<String> listOfStrings = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("key");
```

Answer (score 1):

It's weird, but there is a direct transformation from new JSONArray(stringWithJSONArray) into List.
At least I was able to do like this:

```
public List<String> method(String data) {
    return new JSONArray(data);
}
```